# Adicionar os 5 maiores valores a um array

Tags: java, array

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
public static void topFiveSales(int idEmpresa) {
    List < Entidade > allList = Entidade.findByEmpresa(idEmpresa);
    float totalVendasByEntidade;
    Float[] totais = new Float[5];

    for (Entidade ent: allList) {
        totalVendasByEntidade = entidade.valor;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (totalVendasByEntidade > totais[i]) {
                totais[i] = totalVendasByEntidade;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Qual será a melhor forma de eu receber o valor `totalVendasByEntidade` e adicioná-lo a um `Array` de 5 posições e sempre que recebo esse valor de cada entidade, comparo com os 5 valores do `Array` e caso seja maior que um deles, substitui-lo pelo menor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Vamos fazer em 3 passos o que você precisa.**

**1º)** A sua entidade precisa ser comparada a outra entidade para podermos ordenar a lista. Para isso, vamos implementar a interface Comparable e dizer que ao comparar uma Entidade com a outra, iremos comparar o valor das entidades. Assim:

```
public class Entidade implements Comparable<Entidade>{
   // codigo que ja tinha antes
   @Override
   public int compareTo(Entidade outraEntidade){
        if (this.valor < outraEntidade.valor) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.valor > outraEntidade.valor) {
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
   }
```

**2º)** Para ordenarmos o vetor utilizando as funções da classe Collections, precisamos criar um "comparador" que compara uma entidade com a outra. Faremos isso iremos implementar a interface Comparator, conforme o código a seguir:

```
public class EntidadeComparator implements Comparator<Entidade> {
    public int compare(Entidade entidade, Entidade outraEntidade) {
        return Entidade.getValor().
                compareTo(outraEntidade.getValor());
    }
}
```

**3º)** Por fim, o seu metodo `topFiveSales`, retornará a lista com o listTopFiveSales.

**SUGESTÃO:** métodos representam ações da nossa classe. Para melhor coerência do código, sugiro mudar o nome do método de `topFiveSales` para `listTopFiveSales` ou `getTopFiveSales`

O código dele é simples:

- Busca a lista completa (allList)
- Ordena a lista de forma crescente
- Se tamanho(lista) for menor ou igual a 5 elementos, retorna a lista
- Senão, pegamos os 5 últimos elementos e retornamos
- Coloquei também a opção de retornar a lista crescente ou decrescente

Segue o código:

```
public static List<Entidade> getTopFiveSales(int idEmpresa) {
        List < Entidade > allList = Entidade.findByEmpresa(idEmpresa);
        Collections.sort(allList, new EntidadeComparator());
        List<Entidade> listTopFive = null;
        if(allList.size() <= 5){
           listTopFive = allList;
        }
        else{
          listTopFive = allList.sublist(allList.size()-5,allList.size());
        }
        return listTopFive; //retorna a lista de forma crescente
        // return Collections.reverse(listTopFive); // retorna a lista de forma decrescente
    }
```

**Recaptulando o que foi feito:**

**1)** Nossa Entidade implementou a interface Comparable dizendo como uma Entidade será comparada com a outra.
**2)** Criamos um Comparator que compara 2 entidades.
**3)** Implementamos o método e utilizamos o Collections.sort(array,Comparator) utilizando o comparator que criamos.

Espero ter sido útil.

**Fonte:** [Blog da Caelum](http://blog.caelum.com.br/ordenando-colecoes-com-comparable-e-comparator/)

**EDIT: explicação do método** `sublist`

De acordo com a [documentação do ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), o método
`subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` retorna uma sublista do `fromIndex` **inclusive** até o `toIndex` **exclusive**.

No nosso método utilizamos `listTopFive = allList.sublist(allList.size()-5,allList.size());` Utilizando um array de 7 posições como exemplo : `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` , iremos pegar **size-5 = 2 (inclusive)** até **size(exclusive), ou seja: size-1**
Assim iremos pegar os elementos `[2,3,4,5,6]` que são os 5 últimos do `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma é primeiro ordenar o vetor em ordem decrescente, e aí basta pegar os cinco primeiros elementos do vetor.

```
// Declara um vetor temporário do mesmo tamanho que a lista.
Float[] temp = new Float[allList.size()];

// Adiciona todos os valores para o vetor temporário.
for(int i=0; i< allList.size(); i++) {
    temp[i] = allList[i].valor;
}

// Ordena o vetor em ordem decrescente
Float.sort(temp, (a, b) -> Float.compare(b, a), false);

// Adiciona para o vetor de totais os cinco primeiros maiores valores
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    totais[i] = temp[i];
}
```

Comment: Consegue dar-me um exemplo de como fazer isso ?

Comment: Eu não sei se percebeu mas o meu vetor é de 5 posições e iniciam com todos os valores a 0, e posteriormente é que vai comparando e substituindo.

Comment: Sim, percebi. Atualizei minha resposta com um código de exemplo.

Comment: a variável 'a' e 'b' são o quê? utiliza-se memso assim?

Comment: Podem ser qualquer nome, e são os valores do vetor sendo comparados. Por exemplo, para um vetor [1, 3, 7, 10], quando comparando 1 com 3 para ver qual valor é maior o 'a' seria o 1 e o 'b' seria o três. O processo é repetido para todos os elementos do vetor até que o vetor fique ordenado.

Comment: A questão é que a 'allList' é uma Lista do objeto 'Entidade' e eu preciso de ter acesso a essa entidade para ir buscar o 'valor'

Comment: Um cast não resolveria nesse caso? Como em **temp[i] = ((Entidade)allList[i]).valor**

Comment: Não, não funciona, bem como o Float.sort dá erro :s

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26445/discussion-between-ulysses-alves-and-hugo-machado).

Comment: Hoje estou sem mais tempo :s peço desculpa, estou em trabalho

Comment: @Ulysses Alves, fiz um passo a passo em minha resposta, veja se ajuda

Comment: @HugoMachado veja a resposta